# AngularJS filters dynamic apply depending on expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have snippet of a view. vm.items is an object, each item of object contains an email or phone and the code    correspondingly. For example `{value:'123456', code: 'phone'}`.

```
.contacts
    .contact(ng-repeat='item in vm.items track by $index')
      span {{item | phone}}
```

The question is how could i apply filter only when item is a phone. It means the code of item is `phone`, and when it is an email leave it as is. I thought i could use ternary operator and have something like this: `span {{item | item.code === "phone"? phone : '' }}`, but i didn't succeed. **I cannot change the phone filter code and pass any parameters to this filter. I cannot create new filter for email.**

Comment: what was the error when you tried `span {{item | item.code === "phone"? phone : '' }}` ?

Comment: I got a syntax error
```angular.js:14700 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.' is an unexpected token at column 12 of the expression [item | item.code === "phone"? phone : ''] starting at [.code === "phone"? phone : ''].```

Comment: try `{{ item.code === "phone" ? (item | phone) : item }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do following:

```
{{ item.code === "phone" ? (item | phone) : item }}
```